# Hello world in Goland

Tags: go, goland

I'm following the official Go tutorial: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

But instead of doing things via the command line I'm using GoLand. I'm able to run the program and see "Hello World" printed when everything is contained inside the HelloWorld.go package, but when I add the morestrings package and try to import it in HelloWorld.go I get an import error (`Cannot resolve file 'morestrings'`):

```
package main

import (
    "morestrings"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(morestrings.ReverseRunes("!oG ,olleH"))
}
```

Here's what I've defined the `morestrings` package to be:

```
package morestrings

// ReverseRunes returns its argument string reversed rune-wise left to right.
func ReverseRunes(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }
    return string(r)
}
```

I've set the `GOPATH` in project settings to the root directory of my project (`GoGoHelloWorld`). My understanding is that Go will look for imports starting at `GOPATH`, so I would expect it to find the morestrings package. Here's the file structure:

[image]

Comment: You must use the full path. The example does the same, using `"example.com/user/hello/morestrings"`

Comment: what happens if you run `go build`?

Comment: @rhughes I'm getting an error message `go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'. I get that even with the import commented out, so I must have broken something while tinkering

Comment: @Flimzy the odd thing is that Intellij actually offers to autocomplete the import for me just as "morestrings". Though I still get an error after doing the autocomplete.

Comment: @rhughes I recreated the project. I can build "hello world" now but I still can't import the project. Here's the build output:

`GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/Users/.../IdeaProjects/FinalGoHelloWorld #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/fg/2gwq43b172qcbccjx7_fzlfxsw9zkw/T/___go_build_HelloWorld_go /Users/.../IdeaProjects/FinalGoHelloWorld/HelloWorld.go #gosetup
/private/var/folders/fg/2gwq43b172qcbccjx7_fzlfxsw9zkw/T/___go_build_HelloWorld_go #gosetup
Hello, world.`

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you can take a look at this [go project layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) which may diffs with other language like C++ or Java.
Second, I would like using go module.

Comment: I'm intrigued, but without more context (i.e. how can I use a Go module with Intellij?) this is better as a comment rather than a full answer.

Comment: It's true that I wanted to write a comment rather than an answer, but I got a restriction when I click the comment button below your question. You can take a trial on [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) which is also a JetBrains product. New a project and select `Go Modules`.

Comment: A few days ago, my colleague start a project with `src` directory with go module, but there're some problems that only the main package which is an executable package there and other package can't import or imported from the project other parts.

Answer (score 0):

If your go path is GOPATH=/Users/.../IdeaProjects/FinalGoHelloWorld.
I am assuming you have created a project "GoGoHelloWorld" inside "FinalGoHelloWorld".

Your import statement is wrong, you should use **"GoGoHelloWorld/src/morestrings"**

Answer (score 0):

When you try to import a package in GO, it **doesn't** look for that package everywhere in the whole file system, it looks for that package in specific folders.
These folders are the `src` folder inside your `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` directory.

All your code should be place inside this `GOPATH`'s `src` folder.

You mentioned in the comments section `GOPATH=/Users/.../IdeaProjects/FinalGoHelloWorld`. So you must create a `src` folder inside this directory and all the code goes inside `src`.

So your `GoGoHelloWorld` folder's full path must be `/Users/.../IdeaProject/FinalGoHelloWorld/src/GoGoHelloWorld`, so now your import should look more like

```
import (
    "GoGoHelloWorld/src/morestrings"
    "fmt"
)
```

For reference, since your GOROOT is `GOROOT=/usr/local/go` your fmt package(folder) will be loacted at `/usr/local/go/src/fmt`

I would also recommend changing the `GOPATH` folder name from `FinalGoHelloWorld` to something more generic like `GoWorkspace`. So inside `GoWorkspace/src` you could create multiple projects folders with specific name.

One last thing, create two more folders, `bin` and `pkg`, along with `src`inside `GOPATH`